# in R, group dataframes rows and save into file .txt

Tags: r

i am new in R, i just have some basics idea in developing using R language.
having a dataframe 'df', i need to group rows of dataframe, but its not work using aggregate or by, because i don't have a predefined function.

For example, if the original dataframe 'df' is something like:

```
id size name
1  100  5
2  100  6
3  100  72
4  200  16
5  50   12
```

I would like to have as output :

```
id size name
1  100  5 , 6 , 72
2  200  16
3  50   12
```

and if it's possible, to save output in file.txt? 
i tested with `sink()` and `cat()` but `cat()` don't work with dataframes and lists.

Comment: `aggregate(name ~ size, df, toString)`? Use `write.table` in order to save `data.frame`s.

Comment: What's the purpose of the "id" column in your data? Is it just numbering the rows from 1 to n? I'm asking because it changes id's in your example (e.g. id 5 becomes id 3)

Comment: Yes, it's just to numbering the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is few quick ways to achieve concatenating values of data frame.

***R Code:***

```
# Alternatively toString (@ David Aernburg) you can use c(character) and paste
df_a <- aggregate(name ~ size, c, data =df)
df_a <- aggregate(name ~ size, paste, data = df)


# You can also specify desired separator in collapse
df_a <- aggregate(name ~ size, paste,collapse=",",data=df)

# Using ddply you can specify desired the separator in collapse
library(dplyr)
df_a <- ddply(df, .(size), summarize, rnames = paste(name, collapse = ","))

# Write result to text file
write.table(df_a,file="df_a.txt")
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [dplyr](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html) package:

```
results <- df %>% group_by(size) %>% summarise (rnames = paste(name,collapse = ","))
```